# Distribute NOT across parenthesis in SQL query, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sqlite, parsing

I'm building a parser to turn a search string with Boolean operators and nested parenthesis in it into SQL queries.
A search string like "(Foo Bar) OR (Foo Baz)" generates

```
( "cards"."name" LIKE '%Foo%' AND "cards"."name" LIKE '%Bar%' ) OR 
( "cards"."name" LIKE '%Foo%' AND "cards"."name" LIKE '%Baz%' )
```

OR and AND work fine like this, but NOT doesn't work as I expected. I've done some reading and it looks like it only modifies selectors? I'm pretty unfamiliar.

Is there a way to prefix group of selectors, so that something like "NOT (foo bar)" might expand to the functional equivalent of:

```
( "cards"."name" NOT LIKE '%Foo%' AND "cards"."name" NOT LIKE '%Bar%' )
```

Comment: Ah, yeah updated my question to be a little more clear.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. And can you explain which of these would be selected when user enters `NOT (foo bar)`: `foo bar`, `foo baz`, `bar baz`.

Comment: Why don't you use `'%Foo%Bar%'` instead of searching for parts of text separately?

Comment: @Misa Lazovic: your predicate will not match the `Bar ... Foo` string

Comment: It won't, but the question clearly says "...A search string like "(Foo Bar) OR (Foo Baz)"..."
Not once is Bar Foo mentioned

Comment: @Salman A: Okay, my mistake I skimmed the wikipedia article on De Morgan's laws and thought that you were pointing out a mistake in my second code block. What I'm looking for is a way to exclude the matches made by a group of selectors. So something like NOT ( foo bar ) would return all results that neither match foo, nor bar. Very specifically, I'm wondering if there's a way you can prefix a set of parenthesis to exclude all matches that selectors inside would make.

Comment: @MisaLazovic those are the search terms input by users, not the data. So treat it as a "search engine" query in which the order of terms doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: @Misa Lazovic: That's my mistake, a lack of clarity. When terms are separated by a space my parser infers an AND.

Comment: Try actually writing out your grammar in BNF (Backus-Naur Formulation).